# "Call to a member function isEmpty() on null" when checking if data existed in DB

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So, I have this form where i want to send this values (kode_mk, mk, angkatan, r_seats) to DB, so far it's been successful, but I also want to send this last form named (s_request) which is empty if i haven't send anything yet, and it will automatically be filled with "0" if i successfully send the form with all the values filled (kode_mk, mk, angkatan, r_seats) to DB. I checked it using this `$checkStatus` variable where it use `IsEmpty()` but it returned this error `Call to a member function isEmpty() on null` when i send the form.

```
    public function request(Request $request){

        $check = DB::table('lr2')->where('mk',$request->mk)->first();
        $checkStatus = DB::table('lr2')->where('status_request',$request->s_request->isEmpty())->first();
        if(!$check && $checkStatus){
          DB::table('lr2')->insert([
          'k_mk' => $request->kode_mk,
          'mk' => $request->mk,
          'angkatan' => $request->angkatan,
          'request_seats' => $request->r_seats,
          'status_request' => '0'
         ]);

       }
      else if($check && !$checkStatus){
        abort(404, 'Data existed in DB');
    }
}
```

This is the database migration of 'lr2' table for the measure:

```
   public function up(){

     Schema::create('lr2', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('k_mk');
        $table->string('mk');
        $table->string('angkatan');
        $table->integer('request_seats');
        $table->boolean('status_request');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('id')->references('id')->on('mk');
    });
}
```

Comment: where did you get this from `s_request`

Comment: The Request isn't going to have a collection as an input, maybe an array for an input, but not a Collection unless you some how merged a Collection in

Comment: `s_request` is a form field in my view, previously I always fill either "1" or "0" manually, now i want to leave it blank and automatically assign a value of zero to the column 'status_request` whenever i succesfully send the whole form.

Comment: then you need to check that input for `null` or if it exists at all on the request ... `isEmpty()` is a Collection method which you do not have there, you have a `null`